# How to emit Bloc State based on retry request response?

Tags: flutter, bloc, dio

I tried to implement a refresh token in my app, so every time I do request, dio will check the response, if the response status code is 401 then it will refresh the access token and retry the request

```
Future onError(DioError dioError, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
print(dioError.response!.statusCode);
int? responseCode = dioError.response!.statusCode;
String? oldAccessToken = _sharedPreferencesManager
    .getString(SharedPreferencesManager.keyAccessToken);
if (oldAccessToken != null && responseCode == 401) {
  _dio.interceptors.responseLock.lock();
  _dio.interceptors.responseLock.lock();

  String? refreshToken = _sharedPreferencesManager
      .getString(SharedPreferencesManager.keyRefreshToken);
  Map<String, dynamic> refreshTokenBody = {
    'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
    'refresh_token': refreshToken
  };
  ApiRepository apiAuthRepository = ApiRepository();
  LoginModel token =
      await apiAuthRepository.postRefreshAuth(refreshTokenBody);
  if (token.success) {
    String newAccessToken = token.data.accessToken;
    String newRefreshToken = token.data.refreshToken;
    await _sharedPreferencesManager.putString(
        SharedPreferencesManager.keyAccessToken, newAccessToken);
    await _sharedPreferencesManager.putString(
        SharedPreferencesManager.keyRefreshToken, newRefreshToken);
  }
  RequestOptions options = dioError.response!.requestOptions;
  options.headers.addAll({'requirestoken': true});
  _dio.interceptors.requestLock.unlock();
  _dio.interceptors.responseLock.unlock();
  handler.next(dioError);
  return _dio.request(options.path,
      options: Options(headers: options.headers));
} else {
  super.onError(dioError, handler);
}
}
```

The problem is in my Bloc, if I tried to access the API with the expired access token (If I tried using an active access token there is no problem), the dio works fine by refreshing and retrying the request, but my bloc only emits a Loading/Failure State based on the result of the first response, any idea how to solve it?

```
Future<void> mapEventToState(
  Emitter<DashboardState> emit, DashboardEvent event) async {
emit(DashboardLoading());
DashboardModel getMe = await apiAuthRepository.getMeUser();
if (!getMe.success) {
  emit(DashboardFailure(getMe.message));
}
emit(
  DashboardSuccess(),
);
}
```

And here is how I implement the Bloc

```
BlocProvider<DashboardBloc>(
      create: (_) => _dashboardBloc,
      child: BlocListener<DashboardBloc, DashboardState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is DashboardFailure)
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text(state.error),
            ));
        },
        child: BlocBuilder<DashboardBloc, DashboardState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is DashboardSuccess)
              return ListView(..);
            else if (state is DashboardLoading)
              return Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator());
            else
              print(state);
            return Container();
```

Comment: you have response.lock two times

Answer (score 0):

My English may be bad
This is not Block's problem.
This can be handled in the Services itself, so there is no need for a BLOC
If I understand you correctly, I hope it works

```
InterceptorsWrapper(
    onRequest: (options, handler) {
      return handler.next(options);
    },
    onResponse: (response, handler) {
      return handler.next(response);
    },
    onError: (DioException e, handler) async {
      if (e.response != null) {
        if (e.response?.statusCode == 401) {
          RequestOptions requestOptions = e.requestOptions;
          final token = await newToken();  //Here is a new token acquisition service
          final opts = Options(method: requestOptions.method);
          dio.options.followRedirects = true;
          dio.options.maxRedirects = 5;
          dio.options.contentType = 'application/ld+json';
          dio.options.headers.addAll({
            "Accept": "application/ld+json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
          });
          final response = await dio.request(
              '${requestOptions.baseUrl}${requestOptions.path}',
              options: opts,
              cancelToken: requestOptions.cancelToken,
              onReceiveProgress: requestOptions.onReceiveProgress,
              data: requestOptions.data,
              queryParameters: requestOptions.queryParameters);
          handler.resolve(response);
        } else {
          handler.next(e);
        }
      }
    },
  ),
```

Try it and hope it works.

Comment: Here you will be able to save the old state where the error occurred and resend the request